# How to change the class of one object inside a Vue container?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to cange the class if a single object in a Vue container if a button is pressed. Without a container it's possible to use the v-bind:class option as seen below, but in a container this doesn't work for me. What can I do?

(Just for clarifying, the v-on:click listener works in this example as it should)

sidebar.vue:

```
  <template>    
        <div class="content-list" id="content-buttons">
            <a class="content-list-item" v-on:click="$emit('showece')" v-bind:class="{ 'content-list-item-brand': selectedece }">
                <p style="text-align: center">ECE</p>
            </a>
            <a class="content-list-item">
                <p style="text-align: center">Service2</p>
            </a>                    
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            name:"sidebar" ,
            props: {

            },
        }
    </script>
```

main.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <sidebar v-on:showece="vueshowece"></sidebar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  var showece=false;
  var selectedece=true;
  import sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      sidebar,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        text:'Hallo'

      }
    },
    methods: {
      vueshowece() {
        if (showece==false) {
          showece=true;
          alert("test");
        }  
        else if (showece==true) showece=false;
      }
    },

  };

</script>
```

Comment: What is ```selectedece ```? Give more information about your problem

Comment: selectedece ist just a Boolean variable. Nothing special, just to test wether it will trigger the event and change the class if the variable is true (which it does if I don't use a component). The selectedece variable preferably should be in the main .vue file and not in a component one. The on-click event does work with the $emit syntax and calls a simple function in my main .vue, but the other one doesn't listen to the selectedece variable in the main .vue

Comment: ```selectedece``` mast be in ```data```. Else it not be available in vue template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

First I need to put the selectedece in the data part of main.vue (thanks @an_parubets):

```
data () {
  return {
      selectedece:false,
  }
}
```

After that I need to send this variable to the other component. You can do this with v-bind. See here in main.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <headerbrand v-on:showece="vueshowece"></headerbrand>
    <sidebar v-on:showece="vueshowece" v-bind:selectedece="selectedece"></sidebar>
  </div>
</template>
```

Additionally you need to make the component be able to recieve this value by adding it to the props section (sidebar.vue):

```
<script>
export default {
    name:"sidebar" ,
    props: {
        selectedece: Boolean,
    },
    data () {
      return {

      }
    },

}
</script>
```

Finally the component can change the class while listening to a variable on the main.vue part.

There's a nice introduction to it here: https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-vue/. It helped me finding the error.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedece` variable is not available in your template. Move it to `data`; like this code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container-fluid">
     <div class="content-list" id="content-buttons">
        <a class="content-list-item" v-on:click="toggleClass" v-bind:class="{ 'content-list-item-brand': selectedece }">
           <p style="text-align: center">ECE</p>
        </a>
        <a class="content-list-item">
          <p style="text-align: center">Service2</p>
        </a>                    
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import sidebar from '@/components/Sidebar.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      sidebar,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        text:'Hallo',
        selectedece: true,
      }
    },
    methods: {
     toggleClass() {
       this.selectedece = !this.selectedece;
     }
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify that the sidebar.vue code form above is an extra file/component. I've implemented it in main.vue line 3 so I don't need to put the code in the main.vue file. What you have written works as long as the code is natively in the main.vue but I want it to be in a separate component. This component also provides the option of returning values (although in this case it has no values to return as I think). I've edited the post above so that you see the return part.

Comment: Then you need to transfer into sidebar.vue ```toggleClass``` and ```selectedece``` properties. And use it as props.

Comment: Read about it here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html